# How to adjust the column and row spacing of the matrix in the preamble?

Tags: math-mode, matrices, setspace

How can I adjust row and column spacing of the matrix in the preamble with `\setstretch`?

My original code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setstretch{1.5}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\def
\baselinestretch{1.5}
\setlength\arraycolsep{3.5pt}\selectfont}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.68}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{pmatrix*}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix*} \]

\end{document}
```

I don't know where the code went wrong, so I'm asking for help. First, there are only formulas in the code, but `\setstretch{1.5}` are used for text readability. However, this command also affected the row spacing of the matrix, so I used `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.68}` to adjust row spacing. And I used `\setlength\arraycolsep{3.5pt}` to adjust column spacing in the matrix, but strangely, this code doesn't work without the preceding `\baselinestretch`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest that you load the `etoolbox` package and employ its `\AtBeginEnvironment` macro to prefix the instruction `\setstretch{1.0}` each time a `pmatrix*` environment is started up. Hopefully, your document has but a handful of matrix-like environments that need such attention.

I'd further suggest that you run `\setlength\arraycolsep{3.5pt}` once in the preamble, to make this setting global. Finally, I think you should load the `setspace` package with the option `nodisplayskipstretch`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'pmatrix*' environment
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} % note the 'nodisplayskipstretch' option
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\AtBeginEnvironment' directive
\AtBeginEnvironment{array}{\setstretch{1.0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{pmatrix}{\setstretch{1.0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{pmatrix*}{\setstretch{1.0}}
% etc for other matrix-like envionments that may be in your document

\setlength\arraycolsep{3.5pt} % make this choice global

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2] % filler text
\[ 
\left(\begin{array}{@{} cc @{}} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right) 
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}  
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix*} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix*} 
\]
\lipsum[2] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This code was exactly what I was looking for, but it was really hard to find a solution. The result of compiling the code is very nice. 

However, I have a additional question. When I compile it, warning `Command \normalsize invalid in math mode.` appears in the math mode. I can't find a good reason even after searching, do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @FromLaTeXBeginer - Not sure why these warning messages are showing up, but they look innocuous to me.

Comment: It's certainly not a big deal except for the yellow stripe being a bit annoying. Thank you again!

Comment: @FromLaTeXBeginer - Not sure what you're referring to. FWIW, I don't see any yellow stripes on my screen when I run the code above.

Comment: I look like this. Of course, I think it would be difficult to figure out the reason just by looking at this...
https://i.imgur.com/kOYKOE1.png